# What API can I use to get FAA NOTAMS or will this one I found work?

Tags: weather, faa, software, notam

I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask this because it has to do with APIs with XML/JSON/SOAP, but it also has to do with aviation.

I am in dire need to find an API associated with the FAA to get NOTAMs for areas and airports. NOTAMs are Notices to Airmen, and it will be a useful feature in a service I am creating.

I have done extensive searching for a NOTAMs API, but I cannot find anything except this:
https://notams.aim.faa.gov/notamWFS/

However, this website requires registration which is just a broken link. Any suggestions on how to use this?

Do you know of any other NOTAM APIs available?
Also, if possible, do you know of a weather API which has the same information included in an ATIS/AWOS reporting station?

I was able to find working APIs for US regulations and general weather (not specific enough) and pilot information, but I cannot find any for specific weather or NOTAMs.

**EDIT:** A friend of mine was able to click the registration button, and it didn't give him an error. He sent me the link and I am now trying to register on the site I found.

Comment: If this path does not work, you could still build your own API by scraping the adequate pages. Might end up being somewhat more flexible than  dealing with XML/SOAP requests.

Comment: That approach has a downside @Stanislasdrg, website changes can leave developers scrambling.

Comment: @Forseth11, the ICAO has global notams database which may be of interest: https://www.icao.int/safety/iStars/Pages/notams.aspx.

Comment: @GdD it works! Thanks so much!

Comment: How long did it take them to approve your request? Have you tried www.aviationweather.gov for weather?

Comment: Echoing [Aviaton Weather](https://aviationweather.gov/dataserver) for METAR information. Provides JSON formatted data based on given inputs (GPS, station code).

Answer (score 1):

As @GdD mentioned in the comments, there is an API for NOTAMs here: `https://www.icao.int/safety/iStars/Pages/notams.aspx`

You also asked for metars, which you can get from here:
`http://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/observations/metar/cycles/${TIME}Z.TXT` where `${TIME}` is the hour of the Zulu time you are interest in, wrapped between 0 and 23 (eg. 16)